# Keras DataGenerator using the keras Sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to improve the training speed of my model. I do a bunch of preprocessing and augmentation (which runs at the CPU) that keeps my training slow. So, I tried to implement the loading of data and preprocessing with in a keras `Sequence`. Therefor I followed the [keras docs](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence) and this [stanford exmaple](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly). So far this makes my training much slower, I am pretty sure I have somewhere a mistake. Because running my training script with 4 `workers` and `use_multiprocessing=True` I get the following log:

```
Epoch 8/10
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
8/9 [=========================>....] - ETA: 2s - loss: 444.2380Using TensorFlow backend.
9/9 [==============================] - 26s 3s/step - loss: 447.4939 - val_loss: 308.3012
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 9/10
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Using TensorFlow backend.
8/9 [=========================>....] - ETA: 2s - loss: 421.9372Using TensorFlow backend.
9/9 [==============================] - 26s 3s/step - loss: 418.9702 - val_loss: 263.9197
```

It seems like somewhere in my code TensorFlow is loaded and loaded for every worker (8 because of the validation set?) at each epoch. I don't think this is how a Sequence normally should work?

The DataGenerator:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, annotation_lines, batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes, max_boxes=80):
        self.annotations_lines = annotation_lines
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.anchors = anchors
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.max_boxes = max_boxes

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.annotations_lines) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        annotation_lines = self.annotations_lines[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        image_data = []
        box_data = []
        for annotation_line in annotation_lines:
            image, box = get_random_data(annotation_line, self.input_shape, random=True, max_boxes=self.max_boxes)
            image_data.append(image)
            box_data.append(box)
        image_data = np.array(image_data)
        box_data = np.array(box_data)
        y_true = preprocess_true_boxes(box_data, self.input_shape, self.anchors, self.num_classes)
        return [image_data, *y_true], np.zeros(self.batch_size)
```

Part of my Training script:

```
batch_size = batch_size_complete  # note that more GPU memory is required after unfreezing the body

data_gen_train = DataGenerator(lines, batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes)
data_gen_validation = DataGenerator(validation_lines, batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes)

print('Train on {} samples, val on {} samples, with batch size {}.'.format(num_train, num_val, batch_size))
r = model.fit_generator(data_gen_train,
                        steps_per_epoch=max(1, num_train // batch_size),
                        validation_data=data_gen_validation,
                        validation_steps=max(1, num_val // batch_size),
                        epochs=epochs,
                        initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
                        callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, reduce_lr, early_stopping],
                        workers=workers,
                        use_multiprocessing=True)
model.save_weights(log_dir + 'trained_weights_final.h5')
```

Comment: Slower compared to what?

Comment: to a normal generator like that https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/train.py

Comment: I see you are getting "Using Tensorflow Backend" a lot of times, which seems to be as if Keras were initializing again over and over in each thread. Maybe you should simply try `use_multiprocessing=False` (you can still have lots of workers)

Comment: Thanks this works. And training is much faster. So can you say in general, 'use_multiprocessing' makes only sens for realy lage batches?

Comment: I don't know what `use_multiprocessing` does, actually. All I know is that it has always caused me issues so I never use it.

Comment: And looking at more than 4 "Using tensorflow backend" I can only imagine it's still buggy (unless you notice that you have a number of messages equal to the number of cores in your machine... in that case, training would probably speed up after the last thread is created)

Comment: No I have 4 cores and 8 "Using tensorflow backend", except my old i5-4[..] has hyperthreading, but I don't think so.

Comment: If it stops at 8, then you probably get speed after that point.

Comment: I will try this with a lager dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are getting **Using Tensorflow Backend** a lot of times, which seems to be as if Keras were initializing again over and over in each thread.

Maybe you should simply try `use_multiprocessing=False` (you can still have lots of workers)

Answer (score 1):

The speed of training depends on many factors such as the batch size, size of the input images, learning rate, steps for epoch and steps validation. Then start investigating one of these reasons and put  `use_multiprocessing=False` because 
the various tensorflow backend written during training should not be there.